# ASP.NET Server not resending page to client on C# WebMethod

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, client, refresh

I was using the ASP control for a RadioButtonList, as below, to use the value of the selected radio button to then performe some operations. When the calling code was complete, it seems that the server resent the page back to the client because the client was able to navigate between the 'new' page with whatever modifications I did and the previous page.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioListID" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"       
                             OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioListID_SelectedIndexChanged">
       <asp:ListItem id="OneDayRadioBtn" runat="server" Value="1-Day" />
       <asp:ListItem id="TwoDayRadioBtn" runat="server" Value="2-Day" />
 </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

I had to switch to regular radio inputs and implement them in this way:

```
<body> <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"  
 EnablePartialRendering="true" />
      <!-- Other Stuff -->

<input type="radio" name="radioList" checked onchange="OneDayChecked()"> 1-Day
<input type="radio" name="radioList" onchange="ThreeDayChecked()"> 3-Days
```

...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function OneDayChecked() {
            alert("We do get inside!");
            PageMethods.setTimeFilter(1);
        }
```

... Back on the Server

```
[WebMethod]
public static void setTimeFilter(int filterIndex)
{
     //my code to change text on the client aspx page
}
```

After the WebMethod executes, the client page remains the same. How do I get the server to resend the page to the client? or what can I do to update the client? I've already tried refreshing the client through meta data: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10">`. I'm guessing there's a server side solution but not sure

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing in here is the AJAX (asynchrous) call to server. This won't update your page and that's exactly what's expected in here. Ajax calls are done in the background and they do not affect the client.
If you want to do it with Page Method then you need to return something from it, capture that result in your Javascript code and then manipulate the html on the client side.

Comment: So would I change the return type of my WebMethod to a string, for example, that returns javascript to be excecuted, will that get executed automatically or will i need to call that from somewhere else?